# Factorial recursion implementation using lambda function

Tags: java, lambda

The code which i tried to implement factorial using Lambda function.
The error in the code states that  operator " == " or " - " cannot be applied in the lambda function.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RecFunction {
    Integer recursiveFunction(Integer n);
}
        // Lambda Function
        Integer Fact = (n)-> {
            if (n == 0) return 1;
            else return n * factorial.recursiveFunction ( n - 1 );
        };
```

Comment: Implementing recursion using a lambda is rather nontrivial as the lambda needs to refer to itself and it cannot. There is a canonical solution from functional programming calling a Y Combinator - but I wouldn’t suggest going that route in Java except out of curiosity. What you’re trying do - refer to the current lambda using a variable - is not possible.

Comment: refer to the current lambda using a variable - is not possible.  - ty Boris the Spider

Answer (score 3):

The target of a lambda expression must be a functional interface, not an `Integer`.

Once you resolve that, you'll probably want `Fact` and `factorial` to be the same variable.

That won't be possible if `factorial` is a local variable, but it is possible with an instance variable or a static variable.

For example:

```
class Test 
{
    static RecFunction factorial = null;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        factorial = n -> {
            if (n == 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return n * factorial.recursiveFunction (n - 1);
            }
        };
        System.out.println (factorial.recursiveFunction(5));
    }
}
```

The lambda expression can also be re-written as:

```
factorial = n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial.recursiveFunction (n - 1);
```

This will output

```
120
```